# Need regex for removing easycode from string

Tags: regex, perl

I need the regex for removing easycode from Perl code.

I am using this regex but this is not correct

```
$message =~ s/<.+?>|&[a-z]+;|\[.+?\]/ /g;
```

This regex is removing all code in between `[.+?\]` .

Please let me know if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, that's what the `\[.+?\]` part is matching. Just remove that part (and the preceding alternation operator):

```
$message =~ s/<.+?>|&[a-z]+;/ /gi;
```

(I also think your regex should be case-insensitive)

Comment: in that case it will allow all text between [] but I want to check that it starts with the tag text or with a backlash and then the tag text and allow anything else after that.

Comment: @ABHISHEKGOYAL: Uh, sorry, I don't understand what that means. Could you provide some before/after examples (edit your question to show what the text should look like before and after the replacement)?

Comment: Actually If i am giving this below post this regex is removing all data between []                                                                                              
The dollar sign ($) is used to indicate prices. [ nikon 400 ] and [ nikon $400 ] will give different results.
connects two words, e.g. [ quick_sort ].                                                                     here after using this regex it is removing all [nikon 400] code. but i need to bypass only easycode charaters like [CODE]| [QUOTE] ..

Comment: Can you please offer sample input and desired output? I don't understand the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @test = ("[ nikon 400]", "[ nikon \$400 ]", "[quick_sort]", "[CODE]", "[QUOTE]", "[OTHER STUFF]", "[ test123!%&/(){} ]");

foreach my $line (@test){
    $line =~ s/<.+?>|&[a-z]+;|\[[A-Z]+\]/ /g;
    print "$line\n"
};
```

output:

```
[ nikon 400]
[ nikon $400 ]
[quick_sort]


[OTHER STUFF]
[ test123!%&/(){} ]
```

I can just assume that this is REALLY what you are looking for. Do you want to combine several entries between `[]` like `[quick sort]` will be changed to `[quick_sort]`? This wouldn't be a big issue. But you have to give us additional information about the text (between the brackets) so we can build a good fitting regex and not just a greedy beast.